# Find K distant nodes

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

> Find all nodes, which are at a distance of *k* from the input node.
>
> http://d2o58evtke57tz.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/BinaryTree4.png
>
> **Input:**
>
> `target` = pointer to node with data 8.
> `root` = pointer to node with data 20.
> *k* = 2.
>
> **Output:**
>
> ```
> 10 14 22
> ```

Looking for code-review, optimizations and the best practices.
Note: This question is attributed to [Geeks for geeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-nodes-distance-k-given-node-binary-tree/).

```
class TreeKDNode<T> {
    private TreeKDNode<T> left;
    private T item;
    private TreeKDNode<T> right;
    
    public TreeKDNode(T item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public TreeKDNode<T> getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(TreeKDNode<T> left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public T getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(T item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public TreeKDNode<T> getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(TreeKDNode<T> right) {
        this.right = right;
    }
}


public class KDistanceAway<T> {

    private TreeKDNode<T> root;
    
    public KDistanceAway(TreeKDNode<T> root) { 
        this.root = root;
    }
    
    public List<T> getKNodes(TreeKDNode<T> node, int kthLevel) {
        final List<T> items = new ArrayList<T>();
        search(root, node, items, kthLevel);
        return items;
    }

    
    private int search(TreeKDNode<T> currNode, TreeKDNode<T> node, List<T> list, int kthLevel) {
        if (currNode == null) {
            return 0; 
        } 

        if (currNode == node) {
            searchDown(node, list, 0, kthLevel);
            return 1;
        }
        
        int x;
        // if x > 0, means the desired node was found in leftsubtree.
        if ((x = search(currNode.getLeft(), node, list, kthLevel)) > 0) {
            if (x == kthLevel) {
                list.add(currNode.getItem());
            } else if (x < kthLevel){
                // element was found in the left subtree, now search elements in right subtree that match the level.
                searchDown(currNode.getRight(), list,  1,  kthLevel - x);
            }
            return x + 1;
        } 
    
        // if x > 0, means the desired node was found in rigthsubtree.
        if ((x = search(currNode.getRight(), node, list, kthLevel)) > 0) {
            if (x == kthLevel) {
                list.add(currNode.getItem());
            } else if (x < kthLevel){
                // element was found in the right subtree, now search elements in left subtree that match the level.
                searchDown(currNode.getLeft(), list,  1,  kthLevel - x);
            }
            return x + 1;
        }
        
        // node not found.
        return 0;
    }
    
    
    
    private void searchDown(TreeKDNode<T> currNode, List<T> list, int currentDepth, int depth) {
        if (currNode == null) return;
        
        if (currentDepth == depth) {
            list.add(currNode.getItem());
            return;
        }
        searchDown(currNode.getLeft(), list, currentDepth + 1, depth);
        searchDown(currNode.getRight(), list, currentDepth + 1, depth);
    }
}


public class KDistanceAwayTest {
    
    @Test
    public void testTargetNodeOnLeftOfRoot() {
        TreeKDNode<Integer> root = new TreeKDNode<Integer>(10);
        TreeKDNode<Integer> kd_level1_left = new TreeKDNode<Integer>(20);
        TreeKDNode<Integer> kd_level1_right = new TreeKDNode<Integer>(30);
        root.setLeft(kd_level1_left);
        root.setRight(kd_level1_right);
        
        TreeKDNode<Integer> kd_level2_left_left = new TreeKDNode<Integer>(40);
        TreeKDNode<Integer> kd_level2_left_right = new TreeKDNode<Integer>(50);
        kd_level1_left.setLeft(kd_level2_left_left);
        kd_level1_left.setRight(kd_level2_left_right);
        TreeKDNode<Integer> kd_level2_right_left = new TreeKDNode<Integer>(60);
        TreeKDNode<Integer> kd_level2_right_right = new TreeKDNode<Integer>(70);
        kd_level1_right.setLeft(kd_level2_right_left);
        kd_level1_right.setRight(kd_level2_right_right);

        kd_level2_left_right.setLeft(new TreeKDNode<Integer>(70));
        kd_level2_left_right.setRight(new TreeKDNode<Integer>(80));
        
        
        KDistanceAway<Integer> kd = new KDistanceAway<Integer>(root);

        assertTrue(Arrays.asList(20).equals(kd.getKNodes(kd_level1_left, 0)));
        assertTrue(Arrays.asList(40, 50, 10).equals(kd.getKNodes(kd_level1_left, 1)));
        assertTrue(Arrays.asList(70, 80, 30).equals(kd.getKNodes(kd_level1_left, 2)));
        assertTrue(Arrays.asList(60, 70).equals(kd.getKNodes(kd_level1_left, 3)));
        assertTrue(Arrays.asList().equals(kd.getKNodes(kd_level1_left, 4)));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testTargetNodeOnRightOfRoot() {
        TreeKDNode<Integer> root = new TreeKDNode<Integer>(10);
        TreeKDNode<Integer> kd_level1_left = new TreeKDNode<Integer>(20);
        TreeKDNode<Integer> kd_level1_right = new TreeKDNode<Integer>(30);
        root.setLeft(kd_level1_left);
        root.setRight(kd_level1_right);
        
        TreeKDNode<Integer> kd_level2_left_left = new TreeKDNode<Integer>(40);
        TreeKDNode<Integer> kd_level2_left_right = new TreeKDNode<Integer>(50);
        kd_level1_left.setLeft(kd_level2_left_left);
        kd_level1_left.setRight(kd_level2_left_right);
        TreeKDNode<Integer> kd_level2_right_left = new TreeKDNode<Integer>(60);
        TreeKDNode<Integer> kd_level2_right_right = new TreeKDNode<Integer>(70);
        kd_level1_right.setLeft(kd_level2_right_left);
        kd_level1_right.setRight(kd_level2_right_right);

        kd_level2_left_right.setLeft(new TreeKDNode<Integer>(70));
        kd_level2_left_right.setRight(new TreeKDNode<Integer>(80));
        
        
        KDistanceAway<Integer> kd = new KDistanceAway<Integer>(root);

        assertTrue(Arrays.asList(30).equals(kd.getKNodes(kd_level1_right, 0)));
        assertTrue(Arrays.asList(60, 70, 10).equals(kd.getKNodes(kd_level1_right, 1)));
        assertTrue(Arrays.asList(20).equals(kd.getKNodes(kd_level1_right, 2)));
        assertTrue(Arrays.asList(40, 50).equals(kd.getKNodes(kd_level1_right, 3)));
        assertTrue(Arrays.asList(70, 80).equals(kd.getKNodes(kd_level1_right, 4)));
        assertTrue(Arrays.asList().equals(kd.getKNodes(kd_level1_right, 5)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the diagrams with your question... there's a button on the edit box to do that.

Comment: @Downvoter, could down-vote be supplicated by a reason to down-vote? Downvote without review is very confusing and non-helpful

Comment: Please [provide attribution to your work](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/2.5/in/deed.en_US) when you [copy it from Geeks for Geeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-nodes-distance-k-given-node-binary-tree/)

Comment: I did ... but, there's no need for that. Downvoters have no obligation to comment, and it is neither confusing nor not-helpful. Downvotes mean: "the question may not be clear, may not be useful, or does not show adequate research effort".

Comment: @rolfl provided attribution, also let me know which part of question was not well understood ? In other words its 'a request' to point out issues so that others can review it without hassle that you went through ?

Comment: Right about now this is an 'OK question'. Not great, but it has at least got enough information to survive if Geeks for Geeks goes offline (link-rot). Do you intend to join me for chat in the 2nd monitor?

Answer (score 2):

```
    int x;
    // if x > 0, means the desired node was found in leftsubtree.
    if ((x = search(currNode.getLeft(), node, list, kthLevel)) > 0) {
```

Why make this so complicated?

Go for readability instead:

```
    int x;
    x = search(currNode.getLeft(), node, list, kthLevel);
    // if x > 0, means the desired node was found in leftsubtree.
    if (x > 0) {
```

Additionally, `x` could use a better name, I have no idea what it stands for. You use it both as a temporary variable and as something important. It's... related to the `kthLevel`, but I'm not sure how.